# Django gives 404 error when loading static files AFTER jquery .load is called

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-staticfiles

I have an html file located at

```
/static/templates/usersPostsSection.html
```

in my app directory. The first few lines of usersPostsSection.html are:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static 'css/cssReset.css' %}" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static 'css/homePageBase.css' %}" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>

<form class='voteForm' method="post" action="/post/likePost/">{% csrf_token %}
    <button class="voteButton" type="submit">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="{{ post.id}}" />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.voteForm').click( function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('/post/likePost/', $('.voteForm').serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#content').hide();
            $('#content').load('/static/templates/usersPostsSection.html');
        });
    });
</script>
```

When going to the URL /home/, I see usersPostSection.html perfectly fine. However, once I click the form button and the JS is run, it works up until the last line of the function:

```
$('#content').load('/static/templates/usersPostsSection.html');
```

Once it reloads usersPostsSection.html, nothing shows up on the page and when I use the 'inspect element' on Chrome, it gives errors saying:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/%7B%%20static%20'js/jquery.js'%20%%7D?_=1403660483401 404 (NOT FOUND) 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:2
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/%7B%%20static%20'css/cssReset.css'%20%%7D 404 (NOT FOUND) jquery.js:3
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/%7B%%20static%20'css/homePageBase.css'%20%%7D 404 (NOT FOUND) jquery.js:3
```

I'm pretty sure it is giving this error because it is checking for the static files in

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/
```

rather than using the static location which I have set in my settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/user/Documents/djcode/aS/aSa/static'
)
```

any idea how to stop getting these 404 errors After the .load function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that staticfiles doesn't interpret django template tags in a static html file, so you'll need to write `/static/templates/usersPostsSection.html` as plain html.

`%7B%%20static%20'js/jquery.js'%20%%7D` is just the url-escaped value of `{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}`.

Alternately, you could serve that file via a django view (do you already do this at `/home/`?) and load it from there, instead of as a static file.

Comment: Yea, at /home/ (homePage.html) I just added {% include 'usersPostsSection.html' %} in the template.. so what I decided to do was create a view (which gets called at the URL /temp/usersPosts/) which renders usersPostsSection.html and changed "$('#content').load('/static/templates/usersPostsSection.html');" to  "$('#content').load('/temp/usersPosts/');".. that's what you meant by "Alternately, you could serve that file via a django view and load it from there, instead of as a static file.", right?